# Will a C# BackgroundWorker work on non-multicore CPU?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have an app made using C#, and it uses BackgroundWorker. It will be deployed to client PCs. My question is, will it work (BackgroundWorker) on computers that don't have multicore processors?

Or does the BackgroundWorker only work on multicore processors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work.  When you have more threads than cores, the scheduler will make the threads take turns sharing CPU time.

Comment: In fact, this is precisely how you can have the illusion that multiple things are going on at the same time on your machine. Barring hyper-threading and multiple cores, most things operate serially. They just do it in tiny little slices and really really fast.